# How can i use select * in SOQL query in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am trying to run a select in Salesforce as follows:

```
     SELECT [Account].* FROM [Account] WHERE [Account].Id IN ('123456789012345678')
```

but gives an error:  "Unknown error parsing query"
How can i do this selection ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOQL is not SQL. The SQL syntax you're using here is not valid in Salesforce. You can learn the basics of SOQL in the [Write SOQL Queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) unit on Trailhead or the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm).

Until the Spring '21 release of Salesforce, there is no support for a `SELECT *` wildcard. You must spell out all fields explicitly. Once your org is upgraded to Spring '21 (the release is in progress as of this writing), you'll be able to use [`FIELDS(ALL)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm). At that point, your query would look like this:

```
 SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Account WHERE Id IN ('123456789012345678')
```

Note that you must be using API version 51.0 to connect to Salesforce in order to use this function. You may return up to 200 records.

Comment: thanks for the update. In further reading it looks like as of February 12: All Orgs will now be on Spring ’21!

Comment: Note that if the object has more than 200 fields you may get an error.